# How to make the WebView fullscreen (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a WebView in my app. In the emulator it's working well and stretches over the full screen.
[image: the WebView in the emulator]

But on my phone it looks like this:
[image: the WebView on my phone]

My code looks like this:

```
 WebView(

        initialUrl:
            'myurl',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
```

What can I do that it looks on the phone like in the emulator?

Comment: Looks like you have to add CSS to make the IAB 100% width/height

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: You can use the Chrome Remote Debugging to view the DOM and then make the appropriate CSS tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to wrap webwiev in container and set its width and height to the maximum screen size.

```
Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height ,
     child: WebView(

        initialUrl:
            'myurl',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
)
```

Comment: @BestRazer check my answer.

Comment: Then I get a red screen with text on it (I can't post a picture in the comments)

Comment: @BestRazer So try set just height or use some plugin that let you set webview with fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a bug of my phone. After a restart it worked.